# What was the charge that was given by the Jewish court to Jesus?

Tags: bible, love

I need this for a bible trivia! So I can beat the game and it's rlly important to me, so please tell me.

Comment: What have you done to look up the answer? Have you checked on Google? Wikipedia? In the Bible? If there's no apparent research effort, people will vote this down.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. Before asking further questions, I would suggest taking the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour), and reading the article in the help section on [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem with this question is its trivial nature. Read some sources, maybe *the* source, and you will surely find your answer. That said, it's not actually off-topic, but it does deserve its downvotes.

Comment: Jesus openly admitted to breaking the Sabbath and dietary laws, he took a more liberal view of the laws during a time it was taboo. But ultimately the Romans kill anyone who challenges their authority. Him claiming divinity posed a big threat to them since it could be the makings of a rebellion. The Romans make examples of people like this, hence the cross.

Answer (score 1):

The events surrounding Jesus' death are rife with trickery and very clearly outside of normal legal proceedings for the time. The short answer is that the Jews believed Jesus committed blasphemy, but they had it out for him long before He supposedly did blaspheme.

Before Jesus was captured and executed, the High Priest and his assembly plotted to kill Jesus, seemingly because they did not like the kinds of things he said, but not because he actually broke any law:

> Then the chief priests, the scribes, and the elders of the people assembled at the palace of the high priest, who was called Caiaphas, and **plotted to take Jesus by trickery and kill Him.**
> [Matthew 26:3-4 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026&version=NKJV)

You can see that they wanted him dead even if they had to use "trickery". They did arrest him, but seemingly without cause in the Garden of Gethsemane. He was then taken to the Sanhedrin where he was questioned. This was the trickery. Many false witnesses came out and accused him of many things, but Jesus remained silent. It was not until Jesus spoke that the High Priest declared what Jesus said as blasphemy then demanded that no further evidence was needed to warrant Jesus' execution.

> And the high priest answered and said to Him, “I put You under oath by the living God: Tell us if You are the Christ, the Son of God!”
>
> Jesus said to him, “It is as you said. Nevertheless, I say to you, hereafter you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of the Power, and coming on the clouds of heaven.”
>
> Then the high priest tore his clothes, saying, “**He has spoken blasphemy! What further need do we have of witnesses?** Look, now you have heard His blasphemy! What do you think?”
>
> They answered and said, “**He is deserving of death**.”
> [Matthew 26:63-66 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026&version=NKJV)

They charged Jesus with blasphemy, a very serious crime to the Jews, but meaningless to the Romans, who had the sole authority over penal actions. Nevertheless, the angry mob handed Jesus over to Pontius Pilate, the governor of the area. Pilate questioned Jesus himself to ascertain the truth and what should be done. Pilate eventually determined that Jesus was blameless according to Roman law, so he attempted to have him released. There was apparently a custom where Pilate would release a single prisoner during the Passover feast based on the wishes of the multitude. Pilate presented them with two options.

> And at that time they had a notorious prisoner called Barabbas. Therefore, when they had gathered together, Pilate said to them, “Whom do you want me to release to you? Barabbas, or Jesus who is called Christ?” For he knew that they had handed Him over because of envy ...
>
> The governor answered and said to them, “Which of the two do you want me to release to you?”
>
> They said, “Barabbas!”
>
> Pilate said to them, “**What then shall I do with Jesus who is called Christ?**”
>
> They all said to him, “**Let Him be crucified!**”
>
> Then the governor said, “Why, what evil has He done?”
>
> But they cried out all the more, saying, “Let Him be crucified!”
> [Matthew 27:16-18, 21-23 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2027&version=NKJV)

If Pilate kept records, he probably just picked any number of the false accusations against Jesus, but in the minds of the Jewish mob, Jesus was a blasphemer and deserved death.

**The answer to your trivia question is actually complicated and highly contextual. I would bet that the answer according to the game is "blasphemy".**